# Jquery-Show/Hide-Failing Upon Loading

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

My Jquery is failing to hide my mobile menu upon loading. I have used this code before and it's worked fine - just wondering what I'm missing. Any insight would be helpful. Thank you.

JQUERY

```
var screensize = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

 $(document).ready(function(){

 $(window).resize(function(){   
 if ( width == GetWidth() ) {
    return;
  }
 width = GetWidth();

 if( $(window).width() < 600) {
    $('.link').hide();
} else {
    $('.link').show();
}

}); 

$('header').on('click', function() {
$('.link').slideToggle(500);
e.preventDefault();

});
});
```

SOURCE CODE

```
<nav>
    <ul id="mobile_active">
            <li class="link"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="link"><a href="#">Creative</a></li>

       <li id="logo"><a href="#"><img src="#.png"/></a></li>

            <li class="link"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li class="link"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>

    <header>
        <a class="mobile_menu"></a>
    </header>
```

CSS

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {

header {height:35px;    top:185px; display:block;}

nav {position: relative; top: 113px;}   

nav li a {width:100%; padding:0;}

nav ul li {width:100%; padding:0;}

nav ul li a {color: #949c50; font-size:1em; text-align:center;
border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb1a6; display:block; padding:3%; width:94%;}

nav ul li#logo a {border-bottom: none;}

nav li:first-child {padding-top:40px;}

nav ul li a:hover { color: #FFF;background-color:#949c50;}

nav ul li#logo a:hover {background-color:transparent;}

a.mobile_menu {
 display:block;
 width:100%; height:38px;
 background:#a54499
 url(../links/mobile_link_menu.png)no-repeat 4px 4px;
 position:absolute;
 top:165px;
 cursor:pointer;    }

 a.mobile_menu.selected {background-position: 4px -26px;    }


 li#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution - although I still don't completely understand why this code works and mine doesn't since I'm still struggling with Jquery (If anyone wants to shed some light on that, it'd be appreciated. I'm here to learn). Apparently, I needed the addition of a defined variable and the console.log(width). I found this answer on this site, and would like to give my thanks to the user mrtsherman.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
 var width = $(window).width();
 console.log(width);
 if (width < 600) {
   $('.link').hide();
 } else {
 $('.link').show();
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using CSS media query instead of using javascript? i.e. Set the CSS display of the link to none at default and use the below CSS to show it when the screen size is less or equal to 600px.

```
.link {
 display: none;
}
```

@media(max-width: 600px) {

```
.link {
 display: visible;
}
```

}

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried using media queries for this before - but I run into other problems - here is a link to fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/td5n8ky9/9/ you will notice that initially, everything works fine. However, when you resize the browser (until you see a purple bar) click on the bar, and resize the browser, the navigation disappears. If you double click the purple bar and resize the browser with the navigation showing, it does not return to its normal position.